# Unmarshall single non-root node of a long XML file

Tags: java, xml, spring-batch, xstream

I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<root>
  <header>
    ...
  </header>
  <entries>
    ...
  </entries>
</root>
```

There is a single header node, but a lot of entries.
Is there a way to extract this node as a Java bean, without reading the whole XML file.

If possible, is there any support for this in SpringBatch or XStream?

I don't think using a SpringBatch chunk-oriented tasklet with a `StaxEventItemReader` is appropriate since I just want to read one item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own ItemReader extending StaxEventItemReader (or, better, delegating it), redefine method `ItemReader.read()` and change the condition to indicate reader is "exhausted" just returning null after first valid node read: when Spring-batch found `ItemReader.read()` method returning `null` it will stop processing file.
You can use chunk-oriented and avoid full file read.